# Console error on AJAX request from JS to rails controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, controller

I am having a scenario in which i have to sent a AJAX request from JS to change the boolean value in database column.

Ajax code

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/action"
    });
```

Controller code

```
def action
  current_user.modal.last.toggle!(:boolean-column-name)
end
```

It changes the boolean value in table column successfully. But after that i am receiving an error in browser CONSOLE as below

```
POST http://URL/action
500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I am new to AJAX. What i am doing wrong in ajax request? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use ajax `success` function and handle your ajax respone.

Answer (score 0):

The `500 (internal server error)` means something went wrong on the server's side. It could be several things, but I would start by verifying that the URL and parameters are correct. Also, make sure that whatever handles the request(your `action` method) is expecting the request as a POST.

Write a `success` callback to see what you are getting in response(the last line in your ruby method `returns` automatically in ruby) and and handle the response in the success block.

Answer (score 0):

> 500 (Internal Server Error)

This is a server error. As opposed to 40x errors, 500 means that your code caused [some sort of issue on the server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error).

You can check the response you received (which should show the error) by clicking onto the `network` tab of your browser console (below is Chrome `Right-Click -> Inspect Element -> Network -> Preview`):

[image]

Ultimately, what you have to remember is that if you get a 404 error, it means the resource could not be found; 500 errors are a problem with your code.

--

In your case, I would do the following:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
...
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/action",
   success: function(data){
      // do something on success
   },
   error: function(jqXHR,error, errorThrown) {
     // do something on error
   }
});
```

Without knowing the specific error, you're going to struggle to fix it.